Looking for a proper way of resolving ghost / shadow / mirage left by widget after session_state change (my current workaround is hacky)
Crossposting this from streamlit.io
I have been having issues with ghost / shadow / mirage (or whatever it may be called) that is left by a widget, generally after a change of session_state and with a corresponding change of widgets showing on page.
I do have a hacky workaround and a somewhat deeper insight into what is causing the issue. However, I am really dissatisfied with the workaround, and hope that this discussion can lead to a better solution.
Code to replicate
I created a simple application that can replicate the issue and show the workaround, available here.
EDIT: Posting code of simple_app.py from the above linked repo here as requested by DarkBee:
"""Simple application to demonstrate issue
Run main.py to load this file locally."""

import streamlit as st
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

sessions = {"show_hint": False}
for state, value in sessions.items():
    if state not in st.session_state.keys():
        st.session_state[state] = value

# Some widget on top, to make this feel more like a real application
st.text_input("Type your answer here:")

# Toggling session_state for "show_hint"
if st.button("Show hint"):
    if st.session_state.show_hint:
        print("Hint hidden!")
        st.session_state.show_hint = False
    else:
        print("Hint revealed!")
        st.session_state.show_hint = True

# draws widget only if session_state is True:
if st.session_state.show_hint:
    st.write("Trust yourself!")

display = st.empty()
print(display)

# workaround: move next row "fake_display" from comment to code
# fake_display = st.empty()
while True:
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    display.metric("Current time", current_time)
    sleep(1)

The app consist off:

Input box on top (not linked to anything)
Button that toggles change in session state (“Show hint”)
A text output that shows up depending on session state
A timer that shows current time (placed in a loop)

Description of issue with screenshots
Default state after kicking off:

State after clicking on button and changing session state (showing printout “Trust yourself”):

State after clicking on button again (hiding “Trust yourself”). Now shadow of the timer is visible at the bottom:

Root cause
I placed two print statements in the code. One is to just show what I clicked, the other is to print out information about the st.empty element that is being used for the time display.

What is apparent here is that in the hidden state (“Trust yourself” not show), the _index of the widget is 2, but if I change session and show the “Trust yourself” hint, the _index is 3.
Inferring from above:
Streamlit shows widgets and assigns each an index. In the initial state I only have 3 widgets total:
index 0: text input 
index 1: button 
index 2: timer
In the next session state, I have 4 widgets: 
index 0: text input 
index 1: button 
index 2: text output 
index 3: timer
However, upon hiding the text output, the next page refresh will only replace/overwrite the indexes with the widgets that should be visible this time, so any additional elements still remain:
index 0: text input 
index 1: button 
index 2: timer 
index 3: timer (shadow from previous session)
Workaround
Place another element on the page after the last element, that is otherwise invisible. Then in the next rerun, the indexes will be:
index 0: text input 
index 1: button 
index 2: timer 
index 3: invisible element 
index 4: invisible element (likely shadowing from previous session, but user won't see it)
E.g., in this case a simple st.empty:

Edit: posting code version
# workaround: move next row "fake_display" from comment to code
fake_display = st.empty()

This might work from the end-users perspective, but is bad practice.
I would be happy for any insight about how to properly work around the issue (e.g. without placing as many unused invisible elements in the code as I need to adjust the index for the temporarily shown widgets)

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
